# В php получаю разную область видимости для переменной внутри условия - как исправить?

Tags: php, post, woocommerce

В интернет-магазине есть поля в которые приходят значения из формы `$_POST`, среди которых **billing_email1, billing_email2, billing_email3 и т.д.** в зависимости от заданного количества. (другие поля тоже есть, но нас здесь не интересуют)

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы приходящие значения записать в поля:

В `billing_email` первое значение *billing_email1*, а в
`billing_email_dop` уже все последующие *billing_email2*, *billing_email3* и т.д. через точку с запятой.

Все поля включая `billing_email` заполняются верно, единственная проблема с `billing_email_dop`, которое пустое..

Уже день бьюсь, никак не могу разобраться в чем причина, почему `$key` вне и внутри условия оказываются различными, почему `billing_email_dop` оказывается пустым и как решить задачу.

```
<?php   
    $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        $i = 1;
        $postdata = "";
        $postdop = "";
        $postemail = "";
        var_dump($key); // $key = billing_email_dop есть
        if($_POST["$key"."$i"]) {
            var_dump($key); // $key = billing_email_dop уже нет, вместо него $key = billing_email - почему?
            while($_POST["$key"."$i"]) { 

                if($key==="billing_email") {
                    if(("$key"."$i")=="billing_email1") {
                        $postemail = $_POST['billing_email1'];
                    }
                    else {
                        $postdop .= $_POST["$key"."$i"]."; "; //в $postdop значение записывается корректно
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $postdata .= $_POST["$key"."$i"]."; ";
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
            if($key=="billing_email") {
                woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $postemail );
            }
            else if($key=="billing_emaildop") {
                woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $postdop );
            }
            else {
                woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $postdata );
            }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: А вы не пробовали передовать массив вместо переменных? т.е. в <input type=email name=billing_email1> поменять на name=billing_email[] тогда вы на выходе получите массив, а не кучу переменных и его уже будет легче обработать.

Comment: @Алексей для этого придется кромсать файлы плагина магазина `woocommerce`, т.к. тогда изначально и враперы вокруг поля и лейблы будут иметь одинаковые дивы c id `billing_email[]_field`. Т.е. нужно понимать - стоит ли игра свеч или нужно просто где-то в алгоритме что-то изменить. Не работает всего одно доп поле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение следующее. Нужно было циклы

```
if($_POST["$key"."$i"]) {..}
```

исправить на такие

```
if($_POST["$key"."$i"] || $key == 'billing_emaildop') {..}
```

И вынести

```
$postdop = "";
$postemail = "";
```

за пределы над **foreach**, чтобы не перезаписывался `$postemail = "";`

Спасибо за помощь и наводку @Эдуард

Answer (score 2):

> `var_dump($key); // $key = billing_email_dop есть`
>
> `if ($_POST["$key"."$i"]) {`
>
> `var_dump($key); // $key = billing_email_dop уже нет, вместо него $key = billing_email - почему?`

Почему? -- По условию `if ($_POST["$key"."$i"])`
Пропишите **над** этим условием строку `var_dump($_POST["$key"."$i"]);`, и запустите цикл - так вам станет наглядно видно, какие строки попадают в условие.

Comment: да, я согласен `if($_POST["$key"."$i"]) {..}` не подходит для **$key=billing_emaildop**, но это особо ничего не меняет, т.к. мне нужно получить значения *billing_email2, billing_email3* приходящие с `$_POST["$key"."$i"]` и они проходят проверку `if($key==="billing_email") {..}`
Ну т.е. я по-прежнему не понимаю как решить задачу

Comment: @Вася а если добавить альтернативу "||" (ИЛИ) в условие: `if ($_POST[$key . $i] || $key === 'billing_email') {...}` ? Или так: `if ($_POST[$key . $i] || $_POST[$key] === 'billing_email') {...}`

Comment: в $_POST[$key . $i] содержатся *billing_email1, billing_email2, billing_email3*, и если добавить $key = 'billing_emaildop' (наверное, вы это имели ввиду), то данную проверку проходит, но `$postdop` все равно циклически перезаписывается и все равно к финишу пустым приходит

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $field) :
      switch(true) {
        case $key == 'billing_email_1':
            $billing_email =  $field;
            break;
        case preg_match('/billing_email[0-9]/', $key):
            $billing_email_dop .=  $field . '; ';
            break;
        default:
        break;
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Во-первых, вы зачем-то исключили все остальные поля - я не понял зачем это сделали и не говорил, что это можно делать;
а во-вторых, пытаетесь добавлять зачем-то `$field`, вместо `$_POST`